# Creality Ender3V2 extruder calibration

Tags: creality-ender-3, extrusion, calibration

I have a Ender3V2 Creality 3D printer. I recently changed the extruder for a metal one because the previous was broken.

I have troubles to print now. The adhesion layer peels off easily (kinds of bubbles inside that lift it) and the overall quality is poor.

While looking for a solution, I noticed that my extruder was not calibrated correctly. However, following the standard procedure does not fix my problem. Below is what I did and the results:

[image: Extruder diagram]

The PTFE tube is disconnected to avoid eventual nozzle problem.
I asked for 10 cm extrusion severals times, and the results were as follows (distance in mm):

[image: Experimentation table]

Ratio is *Transmission ratio E*, that I found in **Control** -> **Motion** -> **Transmission ratio** -> **Transmission ratio E**.

I don't understand these results. The initial ratio change should have corrected the under-extrusion. Returning to 93 should also have given me the same result as initially.

I didn't use any G-code, I just used the printer panel (for both ratio changing & asking for extrusion).

I followed this video, [How TO Calibrate The Esteps On A Direct Drive Extruder The EASY Way!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZYdqSUn5E4)

and used this [EStep Calculator – V1.1](https://www.th3dstudio.com/estep-calculator/).

Comment: Can you explain this "Ratio" in this question? What is it? Is this "E-steps"/"Extruder steps per unit?"

Comment: You should try to do it via e.g. Pronterface - like in this video. Additionally, I recommend doing this step by step from [this Teaching Tech's tutorial](https://teachingtechyt.github.io/calibration.html#esteps). It is the same procedure. It is important to not miss any step, because it can give different false results. Let know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that and let you know !

Comment: Hello ! Sorry for the time it tooks me to answer. I know have a raspberry with octoprint to manage this problem. I followed your procedure and my extrusion problem is solved ! I don't exactly understand what is the difference between my previous way to do it, but it works now (my new value is 97.4). Thanks ! I still have troubles printing, but the extrusion step is solved.

Comment: Nice! Consider adding an answer with procedure, which solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @kosteklvp's instructions in commentary, I was able to correctly calibrate my extruder.

Using a third-party app (octoprint via raspberry pi in my case) gave me more flexibility with settings.

Following @kosteklvp's proposed procedure ([at this link](https://teachingtechyt.github.io/calibration.html#esteps)) allowed me to achieve my calibration.

I still have other troubles while printing, but no more related to my extruder.